# Why are hash functions (I.e distributions) used for load balancing

Tags: load-balancing

Beginner coder here self-learning foundational concepts in system design. Have come to load balancing and traditional “modulo-hashing”. While I understand how this works as well as the drawback (in horizontal scaling) - I’m interested, historically - given the available techniques at the time, why a uniformly distributed hash function is used in the first place. Putting cache aside for a moment, why leave it up to a “distribution” and i.e chance vs. always distributing to the server with the least load. It seems simple enough Workflow wise - but clearly there’s either a architectural drawback or a technical limitation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finding that info is expensive, progressively so for large clusters. You want the data very current, you don't want to pick nodes based on their load 1ms ago, the cluster may have accepted many thousands of connections over that 1ms.

Solvable with cooperative load balancing, where each node posts their momentary load to the load balancer. However, that's huge amount of complexity, many new points of failure, and wasted resources too (the nodes could have spent that CPU time and bandwidth doing something useful instead).

There's more. In the web as opposed to application or game servers, connections are short lived, servers + clients are expected to implement sessions at higher levels, with cookies or something. You want requests of the same session arrive to the same node of the cluster, saves huge amount of resources due to caching. If you  over-engineer an efficient way to pick the least loaded node, this may decrease performance by a huge factor because sessions become distributed over multiple nodes.